# Creating a ordered HashMap sorted by create/update time in Java

Tags: java

I am working on data tuples in the following format: [IP, number-of-bytes-served, time]. I created a HashMap on IP to count the number of bytes served for each IP. Then, I realised that I need to remove some least recently used key-value pairs to create some more space. I want to create a time constraint, let's say 1 hour, and remove the key-value pairs with no action in that period. So I need to save the update time for each pair. In fact, for a good performance having the pairs sorted by timestamps seems reasonable.

Thus, what I would like to do is to maintain a sorted list based on the creation or update time of key-value pairs. I need to know these creation and update times explicitly. I came up with two different ideas, but now exactly sure which one to use and how. Here are my two ideas:

- I need a LinkedList with head pointing to the timestamp for the recently updated key-value pair and have this key-value pairs point list nodes.
- I need to maintain HashMap in sorted order based on their creation/update time. Maybe I need to change value from integer to Object with the integer value and a long indicating timestamp.

And the question is how to implement these in Java for efficient add/delete/get performance? Or which libraries I can use to get a HashMap sorted by creation/update time?

Comment: HashMaps are inherently unordered.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to remove values from the map based on age? Or are you wanting to display values in order? How many values are in your map? Right now, you're simply asking how to implement your best idea at a solution to some problem. You'll get better answers if you state your problem and let other people give you potential solutions.

Comment: I am working on data tuples [IP, bytes, time]. I have IPs and the size of bytes served to each IP address. Every time new data comes, I update HashMap. I need to know the time values, so that I can remove the least recently used ones based on some time constraint (let's say one hour) assuming the size of key-value pair is 1K.

Answer (score 2):

Offering my two cents... I recently did something similar (I didn't know about `LinkedHashMap` at the time) where I needed to keep track of some session info.

I ended up using a `ConcurrentHashMap` because multiple user sessions can be active at a time, and run a cleanup every 30 minutes to clear stale session data.  My thought process was, since the app is going to need snappier performance for dealing with session data, I kept the session id as the key.  When I need to clear the oldest data, just grab a list of the values and sort (provided that the class implements `Comparable` or you can write a `Comparator` for it) because this is not done "that often".

Hope that helps.

PS. I'm curious how this compares to the `LinkedHashMap` implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is appropriate, overriding the `removeEldestEntry()` method. The key of this map will be the IP address, the value will be a tuple of `(bytes, last_update)`.

First, you need to create your map using with "access order": this means that any access to a map entry will move that entry to the end of the list (MRU). Then, do the following when you get a new record:

- If map does not contain an entry for an IP, create a new one with number of bytes.
- If map does contain an entry, get the number of bytes from it, *and create a new entry* by adding the new bytes to old. Then `put()` the new entry into the map, replacing the old.

Your tuple should automatically set the time field to current time. But, the thing to understand is that you don't really care about the time, it's simply an attribute used to remove items from the list.

Override `removeEldestEntry()`, and return `true` if the time is outside your bounds.

Although, to be honest I think you'll be better off using a size-based eviction strategy (limit your map to a fixed number of entries). A time-based strategy opens you up to a DDOS attack, in which case you have a large number of entries that come in at once, exhausting your memory.

Comment: One problem with LinkedHashMap implementation would be we may need to remove one than one entry. `removeEldestEntry()` removes only one.

Comment: @mert - Why do you need to remove more than one entry? If your goal is, as you said, "create some more space," then you only need to remove one entry per added entry. There's no reason to clean up more than you need.

Comment: But, if you really want to clean up all your old entries, just iterate the map yourself on add. Not as clean as letting the map do the work for you, but far cleaner than any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by Creation/Update time, you'll need to have that time to do the comparation. That means your object will have to know *when* was it created/updated. This can be accomplished relatively easy by having a `version` field set by default when the object is created and set with a `new Date()` when the object is updated.

There are structures you can base yourself in (`TreeSet` and `TreeMap`, in particular) who implement an order defined by the objects themselves (`Comparable` interface) or a `Comparator`. If you store items that save the date when they were created ir updated, you can implement a comparator that can aid in the sorting process.

If you're restricted to `LinkedList` and `HashMap`, you'll have to sort the list by the use of, for example, `Collections#Sort`. In the case of the `HashMap`, you'll have to sort its Entry Set but since you can't modify it, you'll have to generate a new sorted map this way.

Still, a `HashMap` is a structure that has nothing to do with ordering, so you'll still have some issues when iterating through it. A `LinkedHashMap` could solve this, but again, it all depends on your data type restrictions.